# greater string in java language

Tags: java, string, compareto

The result has to be a string greater than the word "END".
Here is what I've done so far but its just not working.

```
System.out.println("Write a word. The word "END" terminates the program");

String word = sc.nextLine();

if(word.equals("END")){
    System.out.println("Nothing has been typed");
}

while(word!="END"){
    if(word.compareTo("END") > 0){
        System.out.println(word+" is greater than END");
    }
}
```

Comment: `word!="END"` should be `!"END".equals(word)`.

Comment: What you really want to do ? What do you mean by grater than 'END' ?  ENE is graterthan END. ENC is lessthan END. is that what you are doing ?

Comment: yes  @ThilinaHewagama

Comment: @Wooble I am using Java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while(!"END".equals(word))` Your loop condition is not correct

Answer (score 1):

Your lexicographic comparison (i.e. which word is earlier alphabetically) is correct. Your loop condition is incorrect, though:

```
while(word!="END")
```

will always be true. You should change it to

```
while(!"END".equals(word))
```

in which case the loop is going to stop upon reaching the word `END`.

If you would like the case-insensitive comparisons, use `compareToIgnoreCase` instead of `compareTo`, and `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(word!="END") is always true because it check object reference .You should try
while(!"END".equals(word)) where object content is checked
```